# Populating javascript 2D array from php-mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am new to Javascript/PHP, so have a few basic questions. 
I am trying to create a javascript array from php. All goes okay till I am reference collumn '0' or 'pid' from my sql table, but as soon as I try to access the next collumn 'Function' the javascript stops working. I have created a testcase with alert (same to be replaced by an array) 
Would really appreciate all your help.

```
<?php
 $baseName . "jobs";
 $tableName     =   $baseName . "dbTable";
 # datbase info .done. 
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost",$userName,$password);
 if (!$con){
     echo('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db($dbName, $con);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $tableName);
 $count = 0;
 echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Function</th>
 <th>Position</th>
 <th>Location</th>
 <th>Experience</th>
 </tr>";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {  
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['pid'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Function'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Position'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['City'] . ', ' . $row['State'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Experience'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert(<?php echo $row['pid']?>); <!-- this works -->
 **alert(<?php echo $row['Function']?>); <!-- this does not works -->**
</script>
<?php           
 $count++;
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should have put double quote or single quote on your after alert. like

```
alert("<?php echo $row['Function']?>");
```

You get value of first because it is just number Now if it is text you won't get after.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy replies, the double quotes is what I needed. I have learned a lot from this forum!

Answer (score 0):

What is your SQL table structure? Doing $row['name'] will try and get the data under the column 'name'. It must match exactly for it to be able to return data.

Also, the mysql commands are getting deprecated so look into mysqli or PDOs.

Comment: The table headers are: pid|Function|Position|City|Experience,       the 'name' should be fine, as the echo's from php code(inside while) work, also if the name is misspelled or incorrect the alert wreturns an empty string, but atleast works. In my case the browser does not throw an alert if I refrence the collumn headers(other than pid)

Comment: Ah I see, then Vusan's answer is most likely the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For better formatting you might want to use the heredoc (multi-line string) syntax in PHP.

```
echo <<<START
    <tr>
    <td> {$row['pid']} </td>
    <td> {$row['Function']} </td>
    <td> {$row['Position']} </td>
    <td> {$row['City']}, {$row['State']} </td>
    <td> {$row['Experience']}</td>
START;
```